# How to exclude a css class from div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have to include a background image using CSS at the `login` page. However, I don't want to use it on my `home` page. The HTML code is as below.

```
<div data-ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="bg">
    <div data-ng-if="!landingPage" data-ng-include="'view/login.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-if="landingPage=='login'" data-ng-include="'view/login.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-if="landingPage=='home'" data-ng-include="'view/home.html'"></div> <!--I don't want to use CSS class 'bg'-->
</div>
```

and the .css file is

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('/custom/img/pp.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: you need to put this `.bg` style on the home page only then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-class`

```
<div data-ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-class="{bg: isLoggedIn}">
    <div data-ng-if="!landingPage" data-ng-include="'view/login.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-if="landingPage=='login'" data-ng-include="'view/login.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-if="landingPage=='home'" data-ng-include="'view/home.html'"></div> <!--I don't want to use CSS class 'bg'-->
</div>
```

after logging in update the `$scope` variable to true

Comment: @Satya happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the times, you will be adding different background images on different pages so, I would prefer adding it using inline-css.